# Add a comma after the second digit in R

Tags: r

I have a simple question that I am unable to answer:
I would like to add a comma after the second digit of a number.
Transform "12345678" into "12,345678"

Comment: Show your effort...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try `gsub`:

```
gsub("^(\\d{2})(\\d+)","\\1,\\2",x)
```

or another way could be:

```
paste0(substr("12345678",1,2),",",substr("12345678",3,nchar("12345678")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sub`:

```
num <- "12345678"
sub("^(\\d{2})", "\\1,", num)
[1] "12,345678"
```

Note that the behavior of `sub` is that it returns the entire input string in the event that there is no match.  This works well here, because presumably in the case of a string like `abc123` you would just want to get back the entire string unaltered.


### Demo